# Field updated date in view

Tags: 7, rules, datetime

I am using Drupal 7 and I have a view displaying the Updated date.
Unfortunately, the Updated date changes every time I save the node, even if no changes are made.

How can I configure the Updated date to be changed only if changes in fields are made??

P.S: I tried with "Rules", setting as action "Set a data value" and Data selector "node:changed", but it shows me this message: "The selected data property doesn't support writing."

Answer (score 0):

The **Updated date** field is a core property (`node.changed`) of Drupal nodes, representing when it's database record changed. You'd probably have to do some core hacking to rework this property to change only when fields change.

As an alternative, you might want to consider a module like [Track Field Changes](https://www.drupal.org/project/track_field_changes) which logs when specified fields are changed and provides Views integration.